# Htaccess to redirect any folder to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to do the following : redirect ANY folder the user access to the root index and including the folder name in the url parameter.

For instance , if users acces [www.site.com/200](http://www.site.com/200) , it will redirect to [www.site.com/index.php?folder=200](http://www.site.com/index.php?folder=200)

The 200 folder does not exists, i just want the index.php to handle what user inputs as folder.

Here is what i tried :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ../index.php?folder=$1 [L]
```

Somehow it's not working, i get a 404 instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the relative path is throwing it off; try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?folder=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?folder=$1[QSA,L]
```